# How to copy value input text to multiple/array input text

Tags: php, javascript

I need to copy the input text to an array like this:

If the input is "12345":

```
<input type="text" name="data1">
```

Then in text input (array) also written "12345"

```
<? foreach ($countries as $data2)
{
<input type="text" name="$data2['location'][]">
}
```

---

```
<script language="javascript">
function copy() 
{

document.form1.data2.value=document.form1.data1.value
}
</script>
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
<input type="text" name="data1" onKeyUp="copy()"/>
<br /><br>

<input type="text" name="data2">
</form>
```

no problem...

---

But if like this:

```
<input type="text" name="data2[]">
<input type="text" name="data2[]">
<input type="text" name="data2[]">
```

OR in array PHP, like this :

```
<?php foreach ($countries as $data2): ?>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $data2['location'][] ?>" />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

dont work...

---

Comment: Hady, what have you tried yourself? We're not here to do the work of others..? Please explain what you've tried and why this didn't work. Google is your best friend.

Comment: Note that the attribute `nama` isn't going to work.

Comment: "*codes like this*" - that means you have them already? What is your problem? Please ask a **question**.

Comment: is `nama` a typo? or is it in your actual code?

Comment: In my answer I've assumed the name of your control is in your PHP array. If you meant the _value_ of the control, then please let me know and I will modify my answer.

Comment: Now you have edited your question, I can try to guess what you want to achieve. However, we do need you to explain, since I could still be wrong. It looks like you are stating it is easy to copy a single input control, but you are not sure how to copy many array-based input controls?

Comment: Still working on this, @Hady?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to open and close your PHP tags in the right place. If the name of your HTML input control is `$data2['location'][]`, then try this:

```
<?php foreach ($countries as $data2): ?>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $data2['location'][] ?>" />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

So, I've closed PHP mode before and after both the loop keywords (the start of the loop and the end of it). This means that everything outside of those tags is in HTML mode, so to get the name of the control, we need to open the tags again. I've chosen to use `<?php` rather than `<?` because the latter can be turned off on some servers. However, it is fine to stick with the short form if you don't mind that the code is not portable.

Notice also that I've used the colon with the more explicit `end` keyword. This is a popular way of constructing loops in the view layer; for ordinary controller code, I suggest you stick to ordinary braces.

Comment: @Hady: ^ If that is relevant to your question, please edit it into your post, and explain what it is `:)`. Generally, code doesn't format very well in comments, but if you want to add small snippets to a comment, use a pair of backtick (`) characters.

Comment: (My above comment was in relation to a block of HTML from the OP added without explanation, now deleted)